# Form is not sending any data to querystring

Tags: php, html, forms, query-string

I am at my wits end here, I am positive that this is some ridiculous typing error, or I have forgotten to write something.

Anyway I am trying to send data from a form that is inside a twitter bootstrap modal to a file called 'processed.php' which uses the PHPMailer script.
However when I submit the form no data is passed to the query string the url just changes to '/processed.php?'

If anyone could shed some light on it I'd appreciate it very much.

Here's the code:

HTML FIRST:

```
     <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="send-msg" method="GET" action="processed.php">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputNavn">Navn:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-medium required" id="inputNavn">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputTlf">Telefon nummer:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-medium required" id="inputTlf">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputMsg">Besked:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <textarea class="input-large required" id="inputMsg" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" id="inputSend" href="#" rel="popover" data-content="Vi vender tilbage hurtigst muligt." data-original-title="Send besked" data-loading-text="Sender besked…">Send besked</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <div id="results" class="alert alert-info span2">
            <p>Udfyld venligst alle felter.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now the PHP:

```
<?php

$navn= $_REQUEST['inputNavn'];
$tlf= $_REQUEST['inputTlf'];
$besked= $_REQUEST['inputMsg'];

require_once('PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
...(The rest is just the PHPMailer script)

echo $navn;
?>
```

Anyway I am not getting anything in the querystring.
Hope someone can help me.

Thanks alot in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you need to add a `name` attribute to the `input` so that the value is submitted e.g.

```
<input type="text" class="input-medium required" id="inputNavn">
```

should be

```
<input type="text" class="input-medium required" id="inputNavn" name="inputNavn">
```

Comment: Don't think, that's exactly true.

Comment: @علیرضا Care to add any more information so that the answer can be updated if required?

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick answers you guys, can't believe I forgot that! Very much obliged!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to set the name attributes for the form elements.

```
<input type="text" class="input-medium required" id="inputNavn" name="inputNavn">
```

Answer (score 1):

As Smirkin Gherkin said, is necessary to specify a name.

Id refers to the input as an object. This means, you can update or do something with the input using javascript or other languages.

Name is the reference used by the server language to acces the data on that imput field.

If I remember well (this is a tip from my head, probably wrong): you can use javascript with the name of the input, but you can't use php with the id of the input